ROS2 velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
I want to control the motors of a 2 wheel drive utilizing the afore mentioned package. The controller.launch.py file successfully loaded the joint_state_broadcaster, but the velocity_controller always yields an error- "Failed to configure controller".
controller.launch.py file:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager']
    )

    simple_velocity_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['simple_velocity_controller', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager']
    )

    ld = LaunchDescription()
    # ld.add_action(joint_state_broadcaster_spawner)
    ld.add_action(simple_velocity_controller_spawner)
    return ld

My yaml configuration file:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 
    use_sim_time: true

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
    simple_velocity_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
      ros__parameters:
        joints:
        - wheel_left_joint
        - wheel_right_joint

I run: ros2 launch bumperbot_controller controller.launch.py
and end up with this logged to the terminal:
ros2 launch bumperbot_controller controller.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below <path/removed/for/security>
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [spawner-1]: process started with pid [6155]
[spawner-1] [WARN] [1719051409.191143418] [spawner_simple_velocity_controller]: Controller already loaded, skipping load_controller
[spawner-1] [ERROR] [1719051409.193997006] [spawner_simple_velocity_controller]: Failed to configure controller
[ERROR] [spawner-1]: process has died [pid 6155, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/controller_manager/spawner simple_velocity_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].

I'm using ros2-jazzy on an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Edit: These are the logs off the controller_manager:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [WARN] [1719082303.403145970] [gz_ros_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.01 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[ruby $(which gz) sim-2] [GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:189] Trying to deserialize component with data type [N3sdf3v145WorldE], which doesn't have `operator>>`. Component will not be deserialized.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (3)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1719082311.969625877] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'simple_velocity_controller'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1719082312.004632249] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1719082312.058587742] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'simple_velocity_controller'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [ERROR] [1719082312.058976066] [simple_velocity_controller]: 'joints' parameter was empty
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [WARN] [1719082312.059104020] [simple_velocity_controller]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [ERROR] [1719082312.059147270] [controller_manager]: After configuring, controller 'simple_velocity_controller' is in state 'unconfigured' , expected inactive.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1719082312.094528369] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1719082312.095000022] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published

running command- Ros2 control list_controllers- output:
joint_state_broadcaster[joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster] active    
simple_velocity_controller[velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController] unconfigured


Have a look at the console output of the controller manager while you launch the spawners, (ros2_control_node or gazebo/gz_ros2_control, whatever you are using).
You might get a more useful warning there.
If not: What is the status of the ros2_controllers before and after you launch your launch-file?
See ros2 control list_controllers
Edit: There is a clear error in the log:

[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [ERROR] [1719082312.058976066]
[simple_velocity_controller]: 'joints' parameter was empty

See your yaml file, where you had the simple_velocity_controller parameters in the wrong namespace
This should fix your problem
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 
    use_sim_time: true

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
    simple_velocity_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

simple_velocity_controller
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - wheel_left_joint
      - wheel_right_joint


I've updated the original posts with both outputs

see my updated answer

Thank you. I made that change and still getting the same error. I have double checked to ensure no typos

sorry, I was wrong. I udpated the answer. the joints parameter has to be in the namespace of the controller, not below the controller_manager.

Oh I see. Thank you, this worked. Although, I also had to increase the frequency
